# in Opentelemetry, not able to get parent span

Tags: java, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

I am new to OpenTelemetry word. I have created spans for my services separately, but when i am try to combine spans of two different services, using context propogation, I am not able to do it successfully.
I have used following code:

```
 // at client side:
  public static void sendContext(String resource) {

TextMapSetter<HttpURLConnection> setter =
    new TextMapSetter<HttpURLConnection>() {
      @Override
      public void set(HttpURLConnection carrier, String key, String value) {
        carrier.setRequestProperty(key, value);
      }
    };
HttpURLConnection transportLayer = null;
String urlString = "http://127.0.0.1:8080" + resource;
try {
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  transportLayer = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
GlobalOpenTelemetry.getPropagators()
    .getTextMapPropagator()
    .inject(Context.current(), transportLayer, setter);
}



// at server side:
public static Context getContext(HttpServletRequest request) {

TextMapGetter<HttpServletRequest> getter =
    new TextMapGetter<HttpServletRequest>() {
      @Override
      public String get(HttpServletRequest carrier, String key) {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = carrier.getHeaderNames();
        if (headerNames != null) {
          while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println("headerNames.nextElement(): " + headerName);
            if (headerName.equals(key)) {
              String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
              System.out.println("headerValue): " + headerValue);
              return headerValue;
            }
          }
        }

        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Iterable<String> keys(HttpServletRequest carrier) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = carrier.getHeaderNames();
        if (headerNames != null) {
          while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            set.add(headerNames.nextElement());
          }
        }
        return set;
      }
    };
Context extractedContext =
    GlobalOpenTelemetry.getPropagators()
        .getTextMapPropagator()
        .extract(Context.current(), request, getter);
```

At server, i am not able to get parent span.
Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to OpenTelemetry main documentation from [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/). It contains the context propagation part but I used HttpHeader type getter as the TextMapGetter with the same functionality which shows in the doc and instead of using

```
Scope scope = extractedContext.makeCurrent()
```

as the scope to create a child span, better to use directly without the scope,

```
tracer.spanBuilder(spanName).setParent(extractedContext)
```

Because sometimes the automated way to propagate the parent span on the current thread does not work fine.